# "Proof" that weak convergence implies strong convergence, even for infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

We know a result that if for each bounded linear functional $f$ from a normed space $X$ to $K$(its field), $f(x)=0$ then $x=0$. Now if $x_n$ in $X$ is weakly convergent to $x$ then for each bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$ , we have

lim$|f(x_n)-f(x)|=0$

$\implies$ lim$|f(x_n-x)|=0$

$\implies$$|$lim$f(x_n-x)|=0$ (Since modulus function is continous so we can take limit inside)

$\implies$$|f$$($lim $(x_n-x))|=0$ (Since $f$ is bounded so continuous and so we can take limit inside )

$\implies$ $f$$($lim $(x_n-x))=0$

$\implies$ lim $(x_n-x)=0$ (if for each bounded linear functional $f$, $f(x)=0$ then $x=0$ )

$\implies$lim $||(x_n-x)||=0$

This implies $x_n$ is strongly convergent to $x$, hence I proved weak convergrnnce  implies strong convergrnnce. Where I am wrong because in general weak convergrnt does not imply strong convergrnt.

Comment: Where did you cite this result "We know a result that if for each bounded linear functional $f$ from a normed space $X$ to $K$ (its field), $f(x)=0$ then $x=0$". I think it's wrong. Let $X=\mathbb R^2$ and take two orthogonal vectors $x, y \neq 0$. Then $f(x)=(x|y) = 0$ but $x\neq 0$.

Comment: in your example fix y, of course it should be fixed, then think.....  and there is a definition of ||x|| in terms of f, from there the result is correct.

Comment: If it is correct, can you prove it or give a reference for this? Actually, there is a definition of $\|x\|$ in terms of a sequence of functional $f_n$, not only one $f$.

Comment: in  Kreyszig Functional analysis see 4.3-4  (introductory functional analysis with application)

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Then, I think you should check your argument at: $\lim f(x_n-x)=0 \implies f(\lim(x_n -x))=0.$ Here $x_n-x$ might not have limit w.r.t. strong convergence ($x$ is only limit point w.r.t. weak convergence).

Comment: limit is inside because of continuity of f.

Comment: The continuity of $f$ says that: If $x_n\to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, not converse implication.

Comment: as you are saying is same, think

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood something. But if $f$ is continuous and $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, how can you conclude $x_n \to x$? For example, $f(x)=|x|$ and $x_n =(-1)^n$. This is only to illustrative what I said in last comment. Actually, weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence in finite dimension space. If $X$ is infinite dimension then it will fail in general.

Comment: Please stop using the punctuation `!!!`, which is quite useless and somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: The correct statement is: if $f(x)=0$ for $every$ functional $f$ then $x=0.$

Comment: not necessary to consider all f, it is also correct for all bounded linear functional.See corollary 4.3-4 in  Kreyszig's introductory functional analysis with application.

Comment: @Infinity ntt has answered correctly. You can't place the limit inside. If you do so, you already assume that $(x_n)$ is norm convergent. What you have actually shown is the following: "If $(x_n)$ is converges weakly to $x_0$ and if it is norm convergent, then it converges in norm to $x_0$", which is rather obvious.